# Why is realloc giving me inconsistent behaviour?

Tags: c, realloc, memory-reallocation

I am currently taking a procedural programming course at my school. We are using C with C99 standard. I discussed this with my instructor and I cannot understand why `realloc()` is working for his machine, but it is not working for mine.

The goal of this program is to parse a text file `students.txt` that has students' name and their GPA formatted like this:

```
Mary 4.0
Jack 2.45
John 3.9
Jane 3.8
Mike 3.125
```

I have a function that resizes my dynamically allocated array, and when I use realloc the debugger in my CLion IDE, it gave me SIGABRT.

I tried using an online compiler and I get `realloc(): invalid next size`.

I have been trying to debug this all weekend and I can't find the answer and I need help.

My code is currently looking like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INITIAL_SIZE 4
#define BUFFER_SIZE 512
#define GRADE_CUTOFF 3.9

// ERROR CODES
#define FILE_OPEN_ERROR 1
#define MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ERROR 2

struct student {
    double gpa;
    char *name;
};

struct student *resizeAllocationIfNeeded(struct student *listOfStudents,
        unsigned int studentCount, size_t *currentSize) {

    if (studentCount <= *currentSize) {
        return listOfStudents;
    }

    *currentSize *= 2;
    struct student *resizedList = (struct student *) realloc(listOfStudents, *currentSize * sizeof(struct student));
    if (resizedList == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to allocate memory");
        exit(MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ERROR);
    }
    return resizedList;
}

size_t getNamesAndGrades(FILE *file, struct student *listOfStudents, size_t size) {
    unsigned int studentCount = 0;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while(fscanf(file, "%s %lf", buffer, &listOfStudents[studentCount].gpa) > 0) {
        listOfStudents[studentCount].name = strdup(buffer);
        studentCount++;
        listOfStudents = resizeAllocationIfNeeded(listOfStudents, studentCount, &size);
    }

    return studentCount;
}

void swapStudents(struct student *listOfStudents, int x, int y) {
    struct student temp = listOfStudents[x];
    listOfStudents[x] = listOfStudents[y];
    listOfStudents[y] = temp;
}

void sortStudentsByGPA(struct student *listOfStudents, unsigned int studentCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < studentCount - i - 1; j++) {
            if (listOfStudents[j].gpa < listOfStudents[j + 1].gpa) {
                swapStudents(listOfStudents, j, j + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

void printStudentAndGPA(struct student *listOfStudents, unsigned int studentCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++) {
        if (listOfStudents[i].gpa > GRADE_CUTOFF) {
            printf("%s %lf\n", listOfStudents[i].name, listOfStudents[i].gpa);
        }
        free(listOfStudents[i].name);
    }
}

void topStudents(char *fileName) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (!file) {
        perror("Could not open file for reading");
        exit(FILE_OPEN_ERROR);
    }

    struct student *listOfStudents = (struct student *) malloc(INITIAL_SIZE * sizeof(struct student));

    if (listOfStudents == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to allocate memory");
        exit(MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ERROR);
    }

    unsigned int studentCount = getNamesAndGrades(file, listOfStudents, INITIAL_SIZE);
    sortStudentsByGPA(listOfStudents, studentCount);
    printStudentAndGPA(listOfStudents, studentCount);
    free(listOfStudents);
}

int main() {
    topStudents("students.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: You either need to resize the array **before** adding the student, or change `if (studentCount <= *currentSize)` to `if (studentCount < *currentSize)` in `resizeAllocationIfNeeded`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to have a look at my code. 

After changing the condition check, it is still giving me the same behavior. I will have a look on it through Valgrind in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your code: one is just a typo, the other is a more serious logical error.

First, you are reallocating too late, because of the condition in `resizeAllocationIfNeeded()`. When `studentCount == currentSize`, this doesn't resize (even though it should), which makes you overflow the array of students and causes problems.

You can change the condition to fix this:

```
if (studentCount < *currentSize) {
    return listOfStudents;
}
```

---

Apart from the above, your main error is in `getNamesAndGrades()`, where you are reallocating memory and assigning the new pointers to a *local variable*. You then use that variable in `topStudents()` as if it was updated. This will of course not work, as the initial pointer passed by `topStudents()` becomes invalid after the first `realloc()` and memory is irrevocably lost when `getNamesAndGrades()` returns.

You should either pass *a pointer to* the student array, or better just make the function create the array for you.

Here's a solution, renaming `getNamesAndGrades` to `getStudents`:

```c
struct student *getStudents(FILE *file, unsigned int *studentCount) {
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    struct student *listOfStudents;
    size_t size = INITIAL_SIZE;

    *studentCount = 0;
    listOfStudents = malloc(size * sizeof(struct student));
    
    if (listOfStudents == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to allocate memory");
        exit(MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ERROR);
    }

    while(fscanf(file, "%511s %lf", buffer, &listOfStudents[*studentCount].gpa) == 2) {
        listOfStudents[*studentCount].name = strdup(buffer);
        (*studentCount)++;
        listOfStudents = resizeAllocationIfNeeded(listOfStudents, *studentCount, &size);
    }

    return listOfStudents;
}

// ...

void topStudents(char *fileName) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (!file) {
        perror("Could not open file for reading");
        exit(FILE_OPEN_ERROR);
    }

    unsigned int studentCount;
    struct student *listOfStudents = getStudents(file, &studentCount);

    sortStudentsByGPA(listOfStudents, studentCount);
    printStudentAndGPA(listOfStudents, studentCount);
    free(listOfStudents);
}

int main() {
    topStudents("students.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Additional notes:

- When scanning on a fixed size buffer (in this case 512 bytes), use `%511s`, not just `%s`, that's a buffer overflow waiting to happen.
- You are scanning two fields, so check if `fscanf`'s return value is `== 2`, not `> 0`, you don't want for example one field initialized and one not.
- [Don't cast the result of `malloc()` or `realloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- For the future, if you are on Linux, compiling with `gcc -g -fsanitize=address` will give you detailed error reports when something goes bad in the heap, telling you exactly where memory was allocated, freed and used.

Comment: Wow, that was hard to spot. I did not even think about the fact that I need to pass the reference to my malloc array because I am using it in two levels of function calls. Your solution makes much more sense as the code is easier to follow. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You have a fencepost error when checking whether you need to resize the array.

Your initial allocation size is `4`, which means that the highest valid index is `3`.

In the loop in `getNamesAndGrades()`, after you read into `listOfStudents[3]` you increment `studentCount` to `4`. Then you call `resizeAllocationIfNeeded(listOfStudents, studentCount, &size);`

Inside `resizeAllocationIfNeeded()`, `studentCount == 4` and `*currentSize == 4`. So the test

```
    if (studentCount <= *currentSize) {
        return listOfStudents;
    }
```

succeeds and you return without calling `realloc()`.

Then the next iteration of the loop assigns to `listOfStudents[4]`, which causes a buffer overflow.

You need to change that condition to `studentCount < *currentSize`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to have a look at my code. 

After changing the condition check, it is still giving me the same behavior.

Comment: I don't see any other obvious errors. I suggest you use valgrind as someone else suggested.